# Prepare HDD with Linux to transfer to another computer - no CD-ROM/USB

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, installer

I've searched the internet for my question but do not seem to be able to find a direct answer to my question.  If this question belongs in another more appropriate forum, I can re-raise there.

I have upgraded the parts in my computer and installed Windows 10 via following upgrade path from windows 8.  With the old hardware, rather than filling a hole in a ground, I would like to install a Linux OS to try out and experiment.  I am a complete novice regarding Linux.

New System:
ASUS H170A Motherboard, Intel i7-6700, 250GB SSD running as C drive, 2 *250GB HDD running as a RAID 0 using Window storage spaces to create the raid0.  CD-ROM drive - read only.  I do not wish to install Linux on this system.

Left Over parts on which I would like to try and install some version of Linux:
ASUS A8R-MVP motherboard, AMD Athlon dual core 4800+, 4GB Memory, 70GB SATA HDD.
( PSU and case to get second hand! ) - this kit is about 10 years old now.

What I would like to do is the following:
Format/prepare the leftover HDD on the new computer with the installer programs/data. 
Transition HDD over to the old computer, set it as bootable drive( it's the only drive anyway ), and start the chain to do a full installation.

I'm getting the fact I probably need to split the 70GB drive into 2, ( 60GB/10GB ?) so that the smaller partition behaves/acts as a CD-ROM and the OS is installed into the 60GB section.

I do have a spare USB with about 30GB free.  However, I don't think I can set USB as a bootable drive on the A8R-MVP.

Is what I am attempting to do feasible? Is there any easier method( don't wish to buy more hardware beyond PSU/Case - but if it's going to save many hours for the sake of a DVD writer, I'll consider it)?

My presumption was that internet would be full of straightforward guides covering above case but most posts that I have seen seem to assume booting from CD-ROM/USB or creating some sort of dual boot system on current system.  I admit being a complete novice with Linux and so something that does not require reams of unix commands would be appreciated.

I'm agnostic as to which version of Linux I install but to keep things focused, lets say Ubuntu as that appears to quite popular and so hopefully has a lot of support.

Comment: It should be as simply as creating the partition, booting to the installation cd, and install Linux on that partition.  Have you tried that?  That is what every dual-boot tutorial has you to do ( basically 0.

Comment: USB can be make bootable and be used to install linux (in fact I did install ubuntu and opensuse from an USB drive).

Comment: Your manual says you can boot from USB, so you can boot from USB. Use a normal USB boot disk like everyone else.

Comment: When I indicate "boot to installation cd" you can use USB drive also.  It isn't clear the reason a USB drive cannot be used.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would:

1. add the old HDD to your new machine
2. boot into Windows.
3. using your spare USB drive, install a [bootable](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) (live) linux on the usb.
4. Shutdown your new computer and unplug your SDD and RAID drives, but leave the old HDD plugged in.
5. reboot your new computer into linux using the usb drive.
6. install linux to the HDD
7. shutdown, pull out the HDD, and put it in your old machine.
8. boot up the old machine in to linux using the old HDD.

No cdrom required. No need to repartition the old drive.

Comment: On reflection, I was making it a way bigger issue than it was.  End procedure was very similar to above.  Only major difference was that I completely formatted the HDD before preparing the USB on new computer.  Transferred both to old motherboard and just chose the full install option.  Additional things I learnt a) press F8 to select bootable drive on startuo b) use a 2.0 USB stick  c) the board does not have a VGA output! ( still had old graphics card though so was OK ).